# SQL Server Username and Password

Tags: sql-server

Using the example below, which is in my App.Config file, are the uid and password values for the SQL Server, or the SQL Server instance, or for the database that is on the SQL Server?

```
 value="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;"
```

Thanks,
ADawn

Comment: These credentials for authentication are either 1) instance level for a SQL login or 2) database level for contained database user. Most likely #1.

Answer (score 5):

Sql Server separates the concept of a **`login`** from a **`user`**. A server instance itself has *logins*. Individual databases hosted on a server instance have *users*.

When you want to run a query or otherwise interact with a database, you generally first connect to the *server.* You supply a username (uid) and password that match a *server login*. This login in turn maps to a *user* in one (or more!) databases hosted by that server.

You can see the user mappings by opening Sql Server Management Studio and connecting to your server. In the `Object Explorer` area expand the `Security` and then `Login` folders (just under "Databases"). Double-click a login to open its Properties window, and find the `User Mappings` section.

The connection string also includes a *database*. The purpose here is (again) because a login might map to more than one database. Specifying a database as part of the connection provides context, so you don't need a database name with every table reference in your SQL code.

There's also Windows/Active Directory authentication (Integrated Security). This makes things even messier, because you can set up Active Directory *groups* (in addition to users) as server logins to manage access for a number of people at once. An Active Directory user can belong to more than one of these groups... and thus map to more than one user in a single database. In my experience, when this happens you tend to get the union of the set of permissions from every database user you could claim, but I haven't studied that situation thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

```
server=localhost;
```

This is the location of the server.  You can use the IP address or the name of the computer.  Localhost means this code is on the same machine as the SQL server

```
database=myDb;
```

This is your database.  Such as master (which is a system one)

```
uid=myUser;
```

This is a login on the SQL server.  Make sure that login has permissions to the database you are trying to access (and subsequent tables).  See the picture below, that is a login abc_test.

[image]

```
password=myPass;
```

The password for the above user

It is possible to have those Logins as Windows Authenticated logins but in my experience in code it's usually SQL Server authentication (mixed mode) logins.

Answer (score 0):

As sniperd said You can create a new login with a new username and password by right clicking on Logins. Or you can use an existing Login name and change its password. Hope this gonna work!